# flutter: sqflite with bloc

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite, flutter-bloc

i want to build a crud application using sqlite but i can not handle the state of my application using bloc, it is difficult for me to implement bloc in sqflite. Of course, I only have trouble in the bloc section, i mean that I did the CRUD operation in database section completely, but now I can not connect my database with bloc.  i need some example or a project that build using bloc and sqlite i search in google but, cant find any useful project in github it was from 2 year ago . i do not know how many event i should use, and in sqlite when red data from database when the data is so large it made some loading or not.

Comment: If bloc is complicated just use cubit or provider+changenotifier (you dont NEED to use bloc). As for the large data responses just LIMIT your query.